# Recursion for raising a number to a power

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
def power(x, n)
  if n == 1 
    return x
  else 
    x = x * power(x, n-1)
  end
end

power(4, 4)
power(2, 3)
power(10, 3)
power(25, 2)
power(6, 5)
```

It takes the first number and raises it to the 2nd numberth power. So it works for all of them, but I want to write the code in a way that it prints the results for all 5 of the power functions. How do I do this? I tried to modify with puts instead of return but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I assume you want to do this using recursion, but there are other ways as well, such as `x = 2; n = 3; n.times.reduce(1) { |t,_| v = x*t; puts v; v } #=> 8`, which prints `2`, `4`, `8` on separate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable `x` which points to the result of the method call. You can print this and then return it from the function:

```
def power(x, n)
  if n == 1 
    return x
  else 
    x = x * power(x, n-1)
    puts x
    x
  end
end
```

Comment: The code would fail for n==0, and you forgot to remove the `puts` (I guess you had put it there for testing), but aside from this: Why rolling out a recursive method, if one could do simply a `x**n` ?

Comment: This is OPs code, copy-pasted, with a `puts` added because the question specified that was a goal. I was just trying to answer the question here.